# gcov claims that lines not executed - how to fix?

Tags: c, eclipse, gcov

I'm writing a progam in C, using cmocka to unit-test it. I managed to set everything up nicely in Eclipse using MinGW on Windows 10.

The GCC version used is 9.2.0

Flags for compilation are

```
-I"C:\MinGW\cmocka\include" -O0 -g3 -p -pg -ftest-coverage -fprofile-arcs -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -v -fPIC
```

Flags for linker are

```
-L"C:\MinGW\cmocka\lib" -p -pg -ftest-coverage -fprofile-arcs
```

I'm wondering why gcov claims that some lines of code never get executed?

Examples:

[image: Function which is 100% executed]

You can see that the function above is executed to 100%.

[image: Tests to function for 100% coverage]

Above the tests executed to get 100% coverage.

[image: Last line not executed]

Above you can see that the last line seems to be never executed

[image: Test to get 80% coverage]

With the tests above I can only get 80% coverage - According to stats 5 lines are instrumented, only 4 are executed. How to achieve 100%?

[image: GCOV claims that return statement is never executed]

Above you can see that it is even worse, as gcov claims that the return-statement was never executed!

[image: Test that should proof, that return statement is executed at least once]

The test should proof wrong on gcov, obvisously - or am I wrong on this assumption - why?

How to fix this?

EDIT:

After running gcov from command line, thats the output

```
       10:  508:static void vKoCoUpdateDelay(void)
        -:  509:{
       10:  510:  if (0U == control.transfer.u8CyclicDelay)
        -:  511:  {
        1:  512:    control.transfer.u8CyclicDelay = KOCO_U8_MESSAGE_DELAY;
        -:  513:  }
        -:  514:  else
        -:  515:  {
        9:  516:    --control.transfer.u8CyclicDelay;
        -:  517:  }
       10:  518:}
```

Cleary here gcov tells that 100% of the code is executed, also the last line is executed 10 times.

Comment: Did you compile with LTO or any other optimization? I can imagine that on inlined functions the `return` statement (or equivalent closing brace on a `void` function) is not executed, because there is no return.

Comment: please do not post images.  Rather copy/paste the code as (indented) text

Comment: @user3629249 sorry for the pictures, in this case I thought it shows the original output produced by gcov. I did NOT color the code myself, it is the work of the plugin in eclipse to show lines executed.

Comment: @thebusybee compiler flags are given. Using GCC with -O0, so I assume no optimization at all - any ideas?

Comment: regarding the posted linker statement, the trailing options will be ignored because they are after the -L options

Comment: @user3629249 are you sure about this? Then it would be a bug in eclipse CDT as this handles the linker flags automatically in "Properties->C/C++ Build->Settings->MinGW C Linker->All options:"-Textfield, which can't be edited

Comment: Did you try this "outside" Eclipse? I mean, you can call compiler, linker, tests, and `gcov` from the command line, and then look into the annotated source `gcov` produces. I'd check this to eliminate Eclipse's automatism as error - what could be a user error, anyway. ;-)

Comment: Thats interesting, executing gcov from command line it stated that 100% of lines are executed. The last line of vKoCoUpdateDelay is executed 10 times. So it seems to be some kind of issue within Eclipse/CDT with gcov?